# ASP.NET cryptography SHA-1 to SHA-2

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, sha2

Currently, I have source code that is calling external web services that is using SHA-1 cryptography and i'm currently calling these external WS by the following

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2("client.p12", "password");
```

and each time calling the WS I have to pass the variable as per below:

```
 WebserviceName.Timeout = 20000000;
 WebserviceName.PreAuthenticate = true;
 WebserviceName.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate2);
```

Now, I was wondering if .NET framework 4.0 supports SHA-2.

Please advise if X509Certificate2 could be used for SHA-2 and/or any other resource that I could use for this upgrade.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, .net supports sha2 certs. You might need to be running windows 8+ to be able to load the certificates this way.

Comment: @zaitsman, I'm using windows server 2008 r2, but why windows 8+, I didn't get your point. Thank you for your answer

Comment: For 2008R2, you need to install a Windows Update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securityadvisories/2014/2949927

Comment: @zaitsman, thank you, sir. Just one more question, in regards to source code, does (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates) support SHA-2 ? or I would have to use another approach?

Comment: The same managed api is used for both

Answer (score 2):

X.509 certificates themselves do *not* specify which algorithm is to be used for signature generation / verification. An RSA public key can be used for any RSA based algorithm.

Certificates can however be *signed* with an algorithm that uses SHA-1 (usually PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures; PSS signatures usually use SHA-2 but both are compatible with SHA-1 and SHA-2). So you must make sure that your certificate *itself* isn't considered invalid if SHA-1 is not considered secure enough anymore.

SHA-2 has been supported by .NET for a long time (the `SHA256` is even in 1.1), but it never hurts to *test* your configuration.